# Why cometd unsubcribe from subscription doesn't work?

Tags: javascript, java, cluster-computing, failover, cometd

we have found tricky issue on production.
On our frontend we execute following code:

```
cometd.unsubscribe(subscription);
```

but actually this unsubscription doesn't happen.

We have the following configuration:

`nginx`, `zookepper`, 2 `jetty` nodes.

As you understood we use cometd as web socket library.

steps to reproduce bug:

1. we subscribe to node #1 to channel_1
2. stop node #1
3. unsubscribe from channel_1
4. subscribe to channel_2

**Expected result:**

we have subscription to chanel_2 only

**Actual result:**

we have subscription to chanel_1 and chanel_2 only

Please share possible ways to understand the root cause and steps to fix issue.

**P.S.** In server logs I don't see unsubscribe from channel but I see it in ws frames in browser
 **P.S.** Looks like `_clientId` changes after node reconnect and we cannot make unsubscribe with new `_clientId`. Should we unsubscribe in any callback ?

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing,

`cometd.unsubscribe(channel);`

is not the correct way to unsubscribe.
The correct way is:

```javascript
var subscription = cometd.subscribe(channel, function(message) { ... });
...
cometd.unsubscribe(subscription);
```

You have to pass to `unsubscribe(...)` the `subscription` object returned by `subscribe(...)`, not the channel.

This is explained in details in the [CometD](https://cometd.org) [documentation](https://docs.cometd.org/current/reference/#_javascript_subscribe).

Comment: I am sorry. I was errorneous when I wrote the question. Actually I pass subscription to method unsubscribe. And it works correct in regular case, but it doesn't work in case when I shutdown one of the node.

Comment: Your question does not have enough details to understand what you are doing and what does not work. You are welcome to file an issue to https://github.com/cometd/cometd/issues along with a reproducible test case.